# Query multiple databases with variable database names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 15 databases with the same tables that I need to run the same query on and combine. I usually copy and paste the query and rename the database each time but this isn't scalable and I may need to add additional databases in the future.

To avoid having to go and add each one, is there a way I can essentially loop through a table I create with the database name and a few flags and run the query for any database with the correct flags?

Comment: Yes, you can create a dynamic query based on information obtained from tables

Comment: How? I haven't been able to find any resources explaining how to do what I'm trying to

Comment: Google "sql server dynamic sql" and you'll get hundreds of helpful links.

Comment: Assuming all these database all reside on the same sql instance I would leverage sql to build a dynamic sql string and avoid looping entirely. How do you know which databases on the system you want to query?

Comment: "Use DatabaseName GO"? And write queries without database name - just shema.tableName.

Comment: Use database linking and write one master script that UNIONs all the result sets together. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15